Error: [Upstash Redis] The 'url' property is missing or undefined in your Redis config. Facing this error in NEXTJs
I am making a project in NEXTJs , I am building a module of Realtime chat application, using Redis and upstash I created a form that adds as friend it was working fine but suddently out of no where it stopped working and I am facing this error now , I do not have any idea why I am facing this error
'Error: [Upstash Redis] The 'url' property is missing or undefined in your Redis config.'
Now my logout button has also stopped working . Please help me
I tried ChatGpt and youtube
